# Can I help the C# compiler to infer this type?

Tags: c#, type-inference

I'm having an issue with type inference and the C# compiler. Having read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1208764/4265041) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6630690/4265041) I think I understand why it isn't working: what I would like to know is if there is any way I can work-around the problem in order to get my preferred calling semantics.

Here is some code that illustrates my problem (sorry for the length, this is the shortest I could reduce it to):

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

namespace StackOverflow
{
    interface IQuery<TResult> { }

    class MeaningOfLifeQuery : IQuery<int> { }

    interface IQueryHandler<TQuery, TResult> where TQuery : class, IQuery<TResult>
    {
        Task<TResult> ExecuteAsync(TQuery query);
    }

    class MeaningOfLifeQueryHandler : IQueryHandler<MeaningOfLifeQuery, int>
    {
        public Task<int> ExecuteAsync(MeaningOfLifeQuery query)
        {
            return Task.FromResult(42);
        }
    }

    interface IRepository
    {
        Task<TResult> ExecuteQueryDynamicallyAsync<TResult>(IQuery<TResult> query);
        Task<TResult> ExecuteQueryStaticallyAsync<TQuery, TResult>(TQuery query)
            where TQuery : class, IQuery<TResult>;
    }

    class Repository : IRepository
    {
        public Repository(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
        }

        readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

        public async Task<TResult> ExecuteQueryDynamicallyAsync<TResult>(IQuery<TResult> query)
        {
            Type handlerType = typeof(IQueryHandler<,>).MakeGenericType(query.GetType(), typeof(TResult));
            dynamic handler = _serviceProvider.GetRequiredService(handlerType);
            return await handler.ExecuteAsync((dynamic) query);
        }

        public async Task<TResult> ExecuteQueryStaticallyAsync<TQuery, TResult>(TQuery query)
            where TQuery : class, IQuery<TResult>
        {
            Type handlerType = typeof(IQueryHandler<,>).MakeGenericType(typeof(TQuery), typeof(TResult));
            var handler = (IQueryHandler<TQuery, TResult>) _serviceProvider.GetRequiredService(handlerType);
            return await handler.ExecuteAsync(query);
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var services = new ServiceCollection();
            services.AddTransient<IQueryHandler<MeaningOfLifeQuery, int>, MeaningOfLifeQueryHandler>();
            IServiceProvider serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();

            var repository = new Repository(serviceProvider);
            var query = new MeaningOfLifeQuery();
            int result = repository.ExecuteQueryDynamicallyAsync(query).Result;
            result = repository.ExecuteQueryStaticallyAsync<MeaningOfLifeQuery, int>(query).Result;

            // result = repository.ExecuteQueryStaticallyAsync(query).Result;
                // Doesn't work: type arguments cannot be inferred
        }
    }
}
```

Basically I want to get the repository to execute queries simply by calling an `ExecuteAsync` method and passing the query. To make this work I have to use `dynamic` to resolve the query handler type at runtime, as per `ExecuteQueryDynamicallyAsync`. Alternatively, I can specify both the query type and result type as type parameters when calling the method (as per `ExecuteQueryStaticallyAsync`) but this is obviously quite a wordy call, particularly when the query and/or return types have long names.

I can get the compiler to infer both types using a method signature like this:

```
Task<TResult> ExecuteQueryAsync<TQuery, TResult>(TQuery query, TResult ignored)
    where TQuery : class, IQuery<TResult>
```

which allows me to do something like this:

```
var query = new MeaningOfLifeQuery();
...
... ExecuteQueryAsync(query, default(int)) ...
```

but then I have to pass a dummy value (that gets ignored) to the method with each call. Changing the signature to this:

```
Task<TResult> ExecuteQueryAsync<TQuery, TResult>(TQuery query, TResult ignored = default(TResult))
    where TQuery : class, IQuery<TResult>
```

to try to avoid passing in the value when calling doesn't work, as the compiler can no longer infer the result type (ie. back to square one).

I'm at a bit of a loss as to how I can solve this problem, or even if it is solvable. My only options seem to be to stick with the simple calling semantics (but have to rely upon `dynamic`) or to change my architecture in some way. Is there any way I can get the calling semantics I want?

Comment: The compiler must be able to infer the type parameters from the method parameters.  One parameter, two types to infer.  It has no shot at `int`.  Nope, the return type plays no role.  A hacky way is to add an extra parameter to represent the default return value.  That is however easy to push too far.

Comment: Is there any reason you can't remove `TQuery` and just replace with `IQuery<TResult>` everywhere? What does having a separate `TQuery` gain you?

Comment: Unfortunately [constraints are not part of the signature](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8511493/2557128) and won't help you with type inference, and since `TResult` is part of your return value, you can't infer in pieces, that I can see.

Comment: Also, the LDM decided type inference from constraints is [a breaking change](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/5023#issuecomment-170154313) and dropped it. Sometimes it feels like we need C#+ to fix C#.

Comment: @NetMage Two main reasons. (1) The `ExecuteAsync` method in each query handler would no longer be strongly typed, requiring a cast. (2) The dependency injection would no longer work: I need to ask the service provider to "give me a handler for _this_ type of query", but I'd have no way of specifying the type of the query.